# Comparing mini pumps - what to look for and what to consider?

Tags: pump

I plan to buy a mini pump to take on road rides.   My bike has 700 x 25c tires.

There are many different models from each, some with thumb lock levers and some with a hose and screw-in lock.

What do I need to consider, and why, when selecting a minipump ?

Comment: Sorry but product recommendations are off-topic on Stack Exchange. They're purely opinion-based and their applicability can vary a lot by region.

Comment: Oh, i didn’t know. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Lefty I'm going to try saving this with a significant edit.   Feel free to edit further if you feel I've lost anything.

Comment: The longer the pump the better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know a good pump?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/how-to-know-a-good-pump)

Comment: @GabrielC. excellent finding - yes and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/19233/  is also very similar.

Answer (score 2):

You need a pump that pumps air, to the pressure you ride at, through the valve system you have.  And you need that pump on you or your bike, not at home.

Lighter weight is nice, but super light tends to be weak and bendy.

Some pumps allow the use of CO2 which sounds nice, but gets expensive.  Plus that tyre will be low/flat the next morning. So carry a pump as standard and a co2 inflater as optional.

I have 4 bikes.  At a minimum, each has its own pump, tool kit (multi tool, 2/3 tyre levers) one spare tube, and stickers.   That way I don't get stuck somewhere without the bare essentials.   Consider this, should finances stretch that far.

Mini pumps generally come with a clamp that fits under the bottle cage mounts, or some have more unusual mounts.  There's a risk the pump gets stolen if you leave it there, or may vibrate loose and fall off while riding.  A velcro strap helps, or a ziptie that you cut off in time of need.

Comment: I decided to invest on a durable mini pump with great reviews. It’s CNC machined, with a screw-on hose and air-bleed. It doesn’t have the integrated valve core tool coz i wrongly ordered the older model. But it’s ok, i’ll be riding confidently knowing that if an emergency happens, i got this reliable tool with me.